# Retrieving "line unique key" via NetSuite Suitetalk web services

Tags: netsuite, suitetalk

Is it possible to retrieve "line unique key" field for a NetSuite transaction via Suitetalk web services?

"Line unique key" is available of Saved Searches. But I cant seem to find how to retrieve the same via get operation calls on the same transaction or any of the referred records/transactions.

Comment: `Line Unique Key` is not yet exposed either in Netsuite `SOAP` or `REST` based access. The only way you left to access is through the Saved Search itself as prasun mentioned .

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to get the existing saved search result through SuiteTalk i.e. you create the saved search and then reference it in your code.

**Java**

```
public void getSavedSearches() throws RemoteException{
  this.login(true);

  GetSavedSearchRecord record = new GetSavedSearchRecord();
  record.setSearchType(SearchRecordType.transaction);

  GetSavedSearchResult result = _port.getSavedSearch(record);
}
```